# Write to excel file row by row, instead of column by column

Tags: python, arrays, xlsxwriter

I am sorry if the below question is very dumb. I am trying to write an array to file. I tried a few combinations and somehow was able to successfully do this. I don't fully understand how the below work but it works.

I have an array which has a shape (252, 200). When this writes to the file I get 252 columns and 200 rows. I want the 200 data in columns and the 252 data in row.

```
import xlsxwriter as xls
workbook  = xls.Workbook('Lookback_Call.xlsx')
workbook = xls.Workbook('Lookback_Call.xlsx', {'nan_inf_to_errors': True})
worksheet  = workbook.add_worksheet()

row = 0
for col, data in enumerate(tst1):
   worksheet.write_column(row, col, data)

workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`write_row()`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-write-row) instead of `write_column()`:

```
for row, data in enumerate(tst1):
    worksheet.write_column(row, 0, data)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply change

```
worksheet.write_column(row, col, data)
```

into

```
worksheet.write_column(col, row, data)
```

will work. This is a common issue when working with Excel. Excel name cells by "A2" to mean column A (first column) and row 2. Column goes first. This is like a convention in all Excel APIs.

Comment: Everything gets written in the same row now :(

Comment: because you forget to update the row in each iteration! You need two levels of for-loop to scan every element in a 2D array.

Comment: actually no I did this and it works worksheet.write_row(col, row, data)   :)
Don't ask me why, I have no idea but it does.